# How to change my scroll view to scrollable constraint layout or how to use scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-design-library

I want to add more options like add product and etc. but i cant because of scroll view not working properly. the following is my design code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".home">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view8"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/box" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
            android:text="Products"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view8" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view10"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/distribution" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
            android:text="Distributor"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view10" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view10" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cargo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
            android:text="Orders"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view11"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="logout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view11" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_ico"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
    android:text="Hello!"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usertopname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
    android:text="Lakshmanan"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
    android:text="Youre not verified"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usertopname" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample screenshot here

[design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xb8E.jpg)

please update this as scrollable options. thought i can convert scroll view to constraint and it will work and it will be easier to design. but it  doesnt work properly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add more options like this, try recycler view for better performance. If the options are comparatively less, then wrap the top constraint layout inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home">
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view6">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view8"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/box" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
                android:text="Products"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view8" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view10"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/distribution" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
                android:text="Distributor"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view10" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/options_bg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view10" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view11"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cargo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
                android:text="Orders"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view11"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="logout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view11" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_ico"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
        android:text="Hello!"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usertopname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
        android:text="Lakshmanan"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abel"
        android:text="Youre not verified"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usertopname" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but the best practice is to use a recycler view, create an adapter and as many items as you want.